# PHP upload limit (Webmatrix)

Tags: php, localhost, webmatrix

I changed the php upload limit in the php.ini file, but it didn't take effect.

I'm using MS Webmatrix on a local machine, and restarted it if that matters.

I'm not sure what to do?

Comment: Are you sure you chnaged the correct `php.ini` file

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I changed the one at: C:\Program Files\IIS Express\PHP\v7.0
 - In it, it says: "This is php.ini-production INI file"

Comment: Is there another one anywhere? Search for it

Comment: Problem solved, thanks!

Comment: If you have solved the issue, please add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you double check the location of the php.ini file used?

Run the following code:

```
phpinfo();
```

This will give you the PHP settings.
On the 9th row the ini location should be printed (Loaded Configuration File)

If the file path is correct, please share the actual error you are getting.

Comment: I found out that an older version of PHP was actually the one used. Problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran `phpinfo();` then discovered that **another** version of php was actually being used.

So, I edited the right `php.ini` file, which was in a different location.

After restarting WebMatrix, everything worked as expected.